# Global Page Appearance for Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

Is there anyway to set a global page appearance in a given namespace (e.g. `color`,`brush`,`image`, etc) for the `windows phone 8` in `c#`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. You use `ResourceDictionary` for that. Read more about them on this article: [All about ResourceDictionary in WP7](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/all-about-resourcedictionary-in-wp7).

In general, this is what you use for theming. Take a look at [PhoneThemeManager](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2012/01/phonethememanager/) by Jeff Wilcox.